# does XSS filtering in codeigniter doesn't prevent SQL injections?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-injection

i read it some where in form that xss clean in codeigniter dosn't not prevent in sql injection and it should not be used in input but it should be used in output it is true... Please can any one explain.. then how to prevent from sql injection in codeigniter.

Thank you for replaying me..
and sorry for the bad english..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, both topics are not specific to CodeIgniter. 
But CodeIgniter has specific way to handle some of this. Please read https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/security.html

Remember that CodeIgniter will not save you from any of these and you must understand how both of these attacks works.

It is important to understand these are two different attacks, as with any attacks, they could be coupled together. For example using a XSS/CSRF to perform a SQL injection via. a crafted link to a administrator or etc.

XSS is when the attacker can inject code to be executed on the clientside. For example placing a `<script>` tag in your code. This often happens if you output data which the user has provided without sanitizing it or validating it. Typically this could be their username, a post title, $_GET data and etc. There are alot more ways to get a script executed on the clientside other than a script tag, so make sure to read up on the subject.
To avoid it, always escape user inputted data, from any source.
You can read more about it https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

SQL injection is when the attacker can change the SQL query for a malicious purpose. The most common way to avoid injection is to make sure to escape every input, before passing it to a query. Using prepared statement also helps alot. In CodeIgniter, you often use the "ActiveRecord" db thing, which escapes the input for you.
You can read more about it, including examples https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

You should also read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 and become familiar with the most common attacks.

Comment: +1 for the answer, even if I'd like to know if filtering (the CI way) on input helps to protect from these attacks or not.